# Git directory not found

Tags: git, bash

I've been working on a project and using git for version control for a couple of weeks now, and everything was fine untill this morning.
Suddenly, git bash doesn't recognize my folder as a repository anymore.

Here be the folder contents:

[image]

I can see a .git folder being there clearly, but git bash gives me this on `git status`:

```
ict-networks@IT5653 MINGW64 ~/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/osiWorks
$ git st
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I have another project in git, and that's still working fine. The only difference between them is that the working one has a .gitignore, and this one doesn't.

Any ideas on this? I'd love to get this back up in stead of having to make a new repository.

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like you're running `git status` from *inside* the `.git` directory.

Comment: `cd ..` then `git status`

Comment: I'm in the folder where the .git folder is placed. One folder higher would be my projects folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peek inside the `.git` directory.  It should have a file named `HEAD` (all caps, although on Windows or OS X case-insensitive file systems the case of the file name does not matter).  If that file is missing, Git decrees that the repository is not a repository.  Of course, if that file has gone missing, perhaps others have as well, but it can be worth trying restoring that file and see if the rest of the repository is still sensible.

The `HEAD` file normally contains the name of a branch, e.g., `ref: refs/heads/master` (followed by a newline, not a CR-LF pair; also be sure that any editor you use to create it makes a regular, 8-bit text file, not any fancy Unicode or rich-text).

Comment: Yup. That's the problem, HEAD file has gone missing. I'll look into the why and how. I guess I can't bring the HEAD file back out of the blue?

Comment: @VictoriaS. you can just create it in the .git folder, as torek described in the second paragraph. Or easiest is maybe just: make a new folder somewhere, "git init" in that folder, copy paste the HEAD file from this new .git folder to your 'broken' .git folder.

Comment: Well, I guess I lost my commit history so far, but at least it's up and running again. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are any files in .git folder.I can't comment because of low rep.

Comment: There were plenty of files, except the HEAD file was missing, as @torek suggested.